# How to fix syntax errors when opening the terminal window on VS Code on WSL?

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using WSL and VS Code, and when I open the terminal, I see the following errors. Then the python interpreter cannot be found.

What's wrong with my vs code configuration?

```
bash: module: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
bash: error importing function definition for `module'
bash: ml: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
bash: error importing function definition for `ml'
```

[image: screenshot of VS Code]

Comment: Remember that on wsl/linux the python interpreter is called using `python3` not `py` or `python` like on windows.

Comment: Since you mentioned WSL, check your `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc`. VS Code's terminal is probably loading that, and that file has the syntax errors.